# Editing "In:" expression in references Overleaf

Tags: cross-referencing, overleaf, italic

I'm trying to put in italic the expression "In:" in references, regarding "@incollection" e "@inbook" reference types, but I have no idea how to do this. Does anyone have a guess about how to do this? I'm using the abntex2cite package to manage my references, and Overleaf to edit my work.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Please edit your question to show a tiny document compilable document that loads just the `abntex2cite` package along with a sample `.bib` file entry. Are you using the `[num]` or `[alf]` option? You may want to consider using the `abnt` style for `biblatex` which will be much easier to modify.